# Using Flot with Bootstrap 3 Modal, y-axis misaligned

Tags: jquery, css, flot

Does anyone encounter this flot with y-axis mis-align using bootstrap 3 modal? On page it's look perfect:

[image: On page it's look perfect]

But when launch using modal, the y-axis labels mis-align:

[image: but not on modal dialog]

Even if the page re-size, it still the same. I've tried to change the CSS behavior, but still can't. Is this a bug?
I'm using example from http://demo.thedevelovers.com/dashboard/kingadmin-v1.5/charts-statistics.html

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k06ptyzm/2/

`(code omitted)`

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) which reproduces the problem? From screenshots only we can not really help you.

Comment: Hi @Raidri, I've build the fiddle, refer above, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are rendering the Flot chart in an invisible container element. This leads to errors in the rendering. You can see this in an updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k06ptyzm/3/), where the chart in the modal is rendered after a 5 second delay:

```
if ($("#chart-2").length > 0) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        chartYear($("#chart-2"));
    }, 5000);
}
```

- When you open the modal before the chart is rendered, all looks fine including the y-axis.
- When you wait and open the modal after the chart is rendered (like in your original code) the axis is mis-aligned.

So the solution to your problem would be to render the chart only after the modal is opened.

Comment: Got it. meaning it rendered within the container to get the correct axis, and resize of the container will work after that.

Comment: you have any idea why the tooltip can't show in the modal dialog? Updated your fiddles with https://jsfiddle.net/k06ptyzm/3/

Comment: Ok, I've changed the z-index and it works like charm.